# converting an ElementTree to an Element

Tags: python, methods, lxml, element, elementtree

I'm used to operating on `Element`s, not `ElementTree`s.

So far I can convert from an `ElementTree` to an `Element`, using:

```
tree = et.parse(xml_location)
et.fromstring(et.tostring(tree))
```

But this looks expensive - is there a conventional method for converting from an  `ElementTree` to an `Element`, other than the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can simply *get the root of the "tree"*:

```
tree = et.parse(xml_location)  # tree is an ElementTree instance
root = tree.getroot()  # root is an Element instance
```